# ¿Cómo hacer un Response.Redirect("Pagina.aspx") después de descargar un archivo?

Tags: c#, response

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer un `Response.Redirect("Pagina.aspx");` después de realizar la descarga de un archivo, la descarga la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/" + fileName));
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Comment: ¿De que manera descargas el archivo? ¿El código que pusiste pertenece a algún evento?

Comment: El código que puse lo ejecuto dentro del evento Click de un botón que tengo, es que quiero hacer el response.redirect después de realizar la descarga. El archivo se descarga pero cuando hago el Response.Redirect me genera un error que dice que el Header ya fue utilizado.

Comment: Tendrías que manejarlo por JavaScript. Primero iniciar la descarga por JS y luego de X segundos redirigir a la otra página. No te asegura la descarga pero quizás sea lo más cercano a lo que buscas.

Comment: Despues de descargar el archivo se debe ir a una pagina diferente o permanecer en la misma?

Answer (score 0):

**No es posible**

La descarga de un archivo es una respuesta `HTTP 200` a un request que devuelve un tu caso un `application/pdf`.

Un redirect es una respuesta `HTTP 301` con la nueva url seteado en el header `location`

Sos dos requests y responses diferentes.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, de que otra forma podría redireccionar a otra pagina después de realizar la descarga del archivo?

Comment: Te sugiero que sigas el patrón de muchas páginas, que es exactamente lo opuesto: Al hacer clic redireccionarte a la página destino y luego por javascript redireccionar al enlace de descarga

Comment: Es decir que la descarga del archivo lo haga con javascript?

Comment: Por javascript redireccion la página actual a la url de descarga (`window.location.replace("http://url-destino");`). Al no responder HTML sino el archivo, solo una descarga, la página actual no se reemplazará y se siguirá mostrando, a menos que tu nevagdor lee nativamente el archivo que estás descargando y se muestre en luhar de la página

Comment: Julio Moreno Dev En mi caso lo que hago es habilitar o inhabilitar el botón de descarga, tengo una pantalla de descarga, la descargar la hago por la instruccion TransmitFile por si te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

El método que yo utilizo es validar la existencia del archivo utilizando un ciclo while. No es el mejor método, pero es lo que tengo.

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea aceptada editala y pon un ejemplo. Sigue los consejos de [answer]